# The code execution cannot proceed because CONCRT140D.dll wasn't found. Reinstalling the program may fix this probllem

Tags: visual-studio, dll, error-handling, compiler-errors, runtime-error

I am doing some work on Microsoft Visual Studio hen I run the code. I get the only one error which is:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhMEA.jpg)

Error of missing the CONCRT140D.dll file.

The thing is I tried to download CONCRT140D.dll but at the end, the file I found is CONCRT140.dll which isn't the requirement to resolve the error.

My project directory is:

[Project Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCBKv.jpg)

[Project Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NuQl.jpg)

Comment: You should include some code to reproduce the error.
Is the "Face_and_Eye_Detection.exe" is your program / project name?
Which version of Visual Studio you are working with?

CONCRT140D.dll seems to be part of the VC Redist (Visual C++ reedistributable).
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/productinfo/2017-redistribution-vs

Comment: I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 and opencv-3.3.1-vc14.exe in Microsoft Window 10(64-bit).

Comment: This DLL is only available when you have VS2015 installed.  You are linking the wrong build of OpenCV, "vc14" is VS2015.  You'll need to dig up a build for VS2013 ("vc12") or update your VS version.